# How to specify the list of superapp(s) for doorkeeper's skip_authorization block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I wish to [auto-autorize some trusted apps](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Skipping-application-authorization) for our rails API with doorkeeper

```
# Skip Authorization for trusted clients
Doorkeeper.configure
  skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
    client.superapp? || resource_owner.admin?
  end
end
```

According to [this comment](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/488#issuecomment-57256339), it is a concept that app understands.

Should this be done using the client_id(s) whitelisting?
How can I specify the list of superapp(s)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superapp is a concept that is supposed to be custom implemented. 
Ref: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/488 

The easiest way you could auto authorize a trusted app is if you use the trusted client's application id like below:

```
# config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb
  skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
    client.uid == "client application id goes here"
  end
```

Perhaps you could also use scopes and make the client's scopes field to be 'trusted' (As far as I know by directly going to the Database). 

But, I believe, scopes are not supposed to be used this way. They usually notify the resource_owner what type of client it is so that he/she can choose to authorize or not. 
Ref: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes


I hope this helps! It would be nice if anyone has a better way of implementing this though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to create a migration to add a `superapp` boolean field on your `oauth_applications` table.

Then you could do

```
# Skip Authorization for trusted clients
Doorkeeper.configure
  skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
    client.superapp?
  end
end
```

If the application has the superapp boolean set to `true` then the authorization step will be skipped and it will automatically authorize the app without user action.